# React-Native setState - both name and value from the same variable

Tags: javascript, react-native, setstate

Is it possible to enter only one argument to SetState that contains both the name and the value. See the example below. Is there something wrong with the brackets?

This would be handy when changing a lot of states at the same time. That is, first prepare them in one long string and execute setState only once. Thank you!

```
this.setState({myState: "help"}) // this works of course
whatstate='myState'
this.setState({[whatstate]: "me"}) // this too
whatstate2='myState: "please"' 
this.setState(whatstate2) // but how to make this work?
```

Comment: whatstate2 would have to be an object you can't just pass in a primitive int or something like that

Comment: as Ortho said, it should be an object. Put whatstate2 inside curly brackets. `this.setState({whatstate2})`

Comment: Unfortunately, this.setState({ whatstate2 }) does not work. 

Furthermore, if I type this.setState({ 'myState: "fdfdf"' }) Visual Studio Code underlines the closing curly bracket in red - indicating that something it not quite right. I see why the curly brackets need to be there but maybe something else is wrong, too.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// if you like to work only with strings
var whatstate = {};
whatstate['myState1'] = 'help';
whatstate['myState2'] = 'me';
whatstate['myState3'] = 'please';

// ^ this will produce an object equivalent to this
//whatstate = {
//  myState1: 'help',
//  myState2: 'me',
//  myState3: 'please'
//}

// which you can use it to 'setState'
this.setState(whatstate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `this.setState({ whatstate2 })` to achieve the same effect. This is the property value shorthand from ES6.

Reference: https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand

In case you'd like to update multiple states in one go, you can also do that like this.

```
this.setState({
    myState1 : newState1,
    myState2 : newState2
});
```

If the variable names are the same as the state names as mentioned previously, you can do.

```
this.setState({ myState1, myState2 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this.setState({ whatstate2 }) does not work. 

Furthermore, if I type this.setState({ 'myState: "fdfdf"' }) Visual Studio Code underlines the closing curly bracket in red - indicating that something it not quite right. I see why the curly brackets need to be there but maybe something else is wrong, too.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not work"? If you have a valid variable named `whatstate2` and you also have a state named `whatstate2 `. This `setState` will work. However, if the name of your state is `myState`, you need a variable with the same name `myState`.

Comment: If the variable name is the state name it indeed works. Thanks! However, I wanted to change multiple states with one setState command such as changeeverything= 'myState1: "help", myState2: "me"'. I wonder if that is possible.